# Visual studio боковая линия кода

Tags: visual-studio, ide, style-guide

Как отобразить боковую линию, которая поможет ограничивать длину строки кода в редакторе?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начиная с версии 2012, вы можете установить вот это расширение: [Editor Guidelines](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PaulHarrington.EditorGuidelines). Это расширение добавляет вертикальную линию помогающую ограничить ширину строк. Оно позволяет настраивать количество символов и цвет линии.

---

Для более ранних версий Visual Studio я всегда пользовался [этим ответом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84209/adding-a-guideline-to-the-editor-in-visual-studio). Он больше не актуален, но процитирую его для полноты ответа.

Эта функция на самом деле встроена в Visual Studio, но она всегда отключена. Чтобы ее включить, необходимо отредактировать следующую ветвь в реестре: **[HKEY_CURRENT_USER]\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\Text Editor**. Вместо числа 8.0 следует подставить число, соответствующее установленной версии Visual Studio:

**Visual Studio 2010:** HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Text Editor

**Visual Studio 2008:** HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Text Editor

**Visual Studio 2005:** HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\Text Editor

**Visual Studio 2003:** HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\7.1\Text Editor

Создайте новое строковое значение с именем **Guides**, и присвойте ему значение, указывающее цвет линии, и число символов после которого она добавляется. Например: **Guides = RGB(128,0,0) 80**.

Линий может быть больше одной (до 13). Напиример: **Guides = RGB(128,0,0) 5, 80**.

Answer (score 2):

```
{
    "editor.rulers": [100]
}
```

Comment: ответ правильный, но только он для visual studio code, а не visual studio.